# I would like to show messages according to time range between two time stamps

Tags: php, time

My goal to display a message if time range is between given range If not display another one.
I tried;

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Istanbul"); 
$saat = date("h:i");
if ($saat <='08:00' && $saat >='22:00') {
    echo ('yes we are open');
}
    else ('sorry we are closed');{
}
```

I know i make mistake while trying to get that if time is between the range, but i cannot overcome problem.
waiting for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
    $saat = new DateTime(); 
    $open = new DateTime( $saat->format('Y-m-d').' 08:00',new DateTimeZone('Europe/Istanbul'));

  $close = new DateTime($saat->format('Y-m-d').' 22:00',new DateTimeZone('Europe/Istanbul'));

    if (($saat >= $open) && ($saat <= $close)) {
        echo 'yes we are open';
    }else{
        echo 'sorry we are closed';
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly the same code as mine, except you are setting the time zone twice.

Comment: No it is object oriented, i am using DateTime() class.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Istanbul"); 
$saat = date("h:i");
if ($saat <='08:00' && $saat >='22:00') 
{
    echo 'yes we are open';
}
else 
{
    echo 'sorry we are closed';
}
```

Comment: I looked into it but it always says sorry we are closed

Comment: i set closing time to 23:55 before i test it.

Comment: I did not understand why this happens.

Comment: if ($saat >='08:00' && $saat <='22:00')

Comment: definitely because of that :)

Answer (score 1):

Its better to perform a less than / greater than operation on a DateTime object. Also I think you have your `>=` and `<=` confused, and you have an extra bracket.

I changed the name of the `$saat` variable to `$now` to make it more understandable.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Istanbul"); 

//Create a DateTime Object represent the date and time right now
$now = new DateTime(); 

//Today's Opening Date and Time
$open  = new DateTime( $now->format('Y-m-d').' 08:00' ); 

//Today's Closing Date and Time
$close = new DateTime( $now->format('Y-m-d').' 22:00' ); 

if ($now >= $open && $now <= $close) {
    echo ('yes we are open');
}
    else ('sorry we are closed');{
}
```

On a side note, I NEVER use `date()` because of the 2038 problem (google it). `DateTime` is not subject to such problems.

Comment: I cannot get anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the minutes you can do it like this

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Istanbul"); 
$saat = date("h");
if ($saat<=8 && $saat>=22) {
  echo ('yes we are open');
} else { 
  echo('sorry we are closed');
}
```

Comment: Comparing the value of a string to the value of an integer? It may work, but it's not a great coding practice.

Comment: Indeed it's not a great practice but it retains the given code's approach and it works...

Answer (score 0):

you can use your condition like

```
if (strtotime($saat) <=strtotime('08:00') && strtotime($saat) >=strtotime('22:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok  here is the code :

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi"); 
$t=time();
//echo(date("H:i",$t)); // Current Time
$hour = (date("H",$t)); // Current Hour
$minute = (date("i",$t)); //Current Minute


if (($hour <= 8)&&($hour >= 22)) {
    echo "We are open";
}
else {
    echo "sorry we are closed";
}
```